# - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didReadData delegate not called?

Tags: objective-c, xmppframework

I am using `Xmpp` `framework` without using `pods`but delegate `didReadData` not called after sending a packet.

```
-(void)setupStream 
{
    xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];

    [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = XMPPStreamStartTLSPolicyRequired;

    [xmppStream setHostName:@"37.247.116.191"];

    [xmppStream setHostPort:5222];

}
```

Comment: i am sending "<stream:stream xmlns='a:c' xmlns:stream='glabbr:stream' version='1.0' to='glabbr.co.in'>" to server....but receive nothing...plz help me

Comment: i m using Xmpp framework without using pods....but  delegate didReadData not called after sending a packet....plz help me

Comment: i m connecting to our sever(see in code)but the delegate method not called....thanks